# Decrypt AWS managed keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, key, managed

Is there a way to decrypt the AWS managed keys?

AWS managed keys have been applied as default for root volumes/EBS & AMI, which is preventing sharing of AMI/snapshots across other AWS accounts & regions.

How to create an unencrypted AMI or decrypt the AWS managed keys?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to share encrypted AMI's across accounts which I'll detail below.
To answer the original question: you can't decrypt an encrypted AMI and you can't decrypt AWS managed keys.

What you can do is create a CMK (Customer Master Key), re-encrypt your image with the new key, and share it with the account(s) you wish.

> If you are starting with snapshots encrypted under the default EBS CMK (with the key alias, aws/ebs), copy those snapshots and reencrypt them under a custom CMK you created in KMS. You will then be able to modify the key policy on the custom CMK to be able to grant access to the key to any number of external accounts.

1. Create an AWS KMS customer master key (CMK)
2. Create a policy in the source account with permissions to share the AMI, using the ec2 `ModifyImageAttribute` operation
3. Add the target account to the CMK created in step 1.  (In **Other AWS Accounts** subsection)
4. Create a policy on the target account to the AWS KMS operations.  Allow kms actions - `DescribeKey`, `ReEncrypt*`, `CreateGrant`, and `Decrypt`.
5. You can then share the key using a CLI command like the following:
   `aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id <ami-12345678> --launch-permission "Add=[{UserId=<target account number>}]"`

The attached references go into much greater detail about this process.

**References**
[How To Share Encrypted AMIs Across Accounts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-share-encrypted-amis-across-accounts-to-launch-encrypted-ec2-instances/)
[How To Create a Custom AMI with Encrypted EBS and Share It](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-a-custom-ami-with-encrypted-amazon-ebs-snapshots-and-share-it-with-other-accounts-and-regions/)